# Project plan audit

Tags: planning

I has been tasked to audit a project plan by 3rd party vendor.
The vendor is gonna use Scrum and going to provide a project plan.

I understand that every plan must fit to the particular project scope, but I think that there must be publicly available templates for such kind of audits.

Could you suggest where should I look ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this audit? To assess if the plan is feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before a thorough answer please check the PMBOK or similar for "formal project plans", otherwise you might miss some of the 12 or so chapters. Some of these chapters can be not applicable for your particular case.

I'd for sure try to get a RACI matrix of the company, be it written or not. (Who's responsible/accountable for what).

How formal you will dive for the audit depends on how formal your audit and project is. For large scale projects there are several plans, forming the Project Plan.